# Passing Value to a shell script via ssh

Tags: shell

I want to pass a value to the shell script via ssh:

1. I have two Linux machines: machine1 and machine2
2. I have two scripts on those machines: "script1" on machine1 and "script2" machine2.
3. I have done ssh setting so I can login to machine2 from machine1 without password

   #### /opt/script1

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   echo "enter your name"
   read name
   ssh root@machine2 "/opt/script2 $name"
   ```

   #### /opt/script2

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   echo "$name"
   ```
4. but no string is printing

Please let me know the procedure to do this.

Comment: First things first: change `/opt/script2` to do: `echo "Name: $name"`.  Now you should get some output even if the variable is not being set.  If you don't get any output even so, you need to track down what is being executed (add `set -x` as the first line of `/opt/script2`, perhaps).  If you get some output, then you can track down what happens on machine1.  You could usefully add `echo "Name: $nme"` to `/opt/script1`, too.  Do you need to run: `ssh root@machine2 sh -c "/opt/script2 $name"`?

Comment: Shebangs (first commented line containing path to binary interpreter) are not useless! Even on SO, this may help formatting!

Answer (score 0):

can u try the scripts like this

script1.sh

```
echo "enter your name"
read name
ssh root@machine2 "/opt/script2.sh $name"
```

script2.sh

```
echo $1
```

Passing command-line parameter to shell script

$0 is the name of the command

$1 first parameter

$2 second parameter

$3 third parameter etc. etc

$# total number of parameters

$@ all the parameters will be listed

Answer (score 0):

If i entered my name as Rupert script1 would be doing this

```
ssh root@machine2 "/opt/script2 Rupert"
```

Script2 is looking for $name but this has not been set on machine2 so the script will print nothing.

You can edit script2 to the below

```
#!/bin/sh
name=$1
echo "$name"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the script 1 as following:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "enter your name"
read name
ssh root@machine2 `/opt/script2 $name`
```